# Making html table elements responsive for horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I know there's lots on the internet about this, but I can't seem to get the elements inside my table to be responsive for a horizontally scrolling app.

I've made the table itself responsive by wrapping my entire table in

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;"></div>
```

As you can see by the proper margins on the side of the table.

[image]

**The problem:** As the screen shrinks, the text is center-aligned, so it remains in the center of the entire page view that needs to be scrolled, it doesn't move to the center of the shrunken table row.

I want the app to look like the first image, even as the page shrinks.

[image]

Using `meta` on `viewport` does not make the table responsive. I think it could be possible that the file is html4 but I'm not sure how to know for sure based on the code in the file, so I included the html code below.

I've tried using media queries like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Just to test if I can get one to work, but this isn't even changing the background color of the app when the width is 1000px or smaller.

It doesn't matter if I specify center, left or right, the text gets cut off as the table shrinks.

**UPDATE:**

I've split the header and the contents into their own separate containers, which accomplishes the goal of the header being responsive, but it defeats the design.

[image]

I need to keep the header as the same width as the table contents, so I believe the header and the contents cannot be in their own containers in order to accomplish this.

I would like the app to look like this image below:

[image]

The header needs to be responsive while still being connected to the overall table.

**Updated Problem:** How can I make the table header responsive while keeping the header width to always be the same as the rest of the table, no matter how the screen is adjusted.

Here's the html:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h2 id="title" class="hidden" align="center">OIT Facilities Costs<p id="subtitle">by location<p>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <p>This application visualizes 3 kinds of data </p>
    <br>
    <div id="dashboard1-div" align="center">
        <div id="charts1-div">

            <div id="tablediv">
                <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                    <table class="container">


                        <tbody>

                            <tr id="tr-test">
                                <td>

                                    <p id="table1-heading" class="hidden">OIT Work Order Maintenance Costs</p>


                                    <button id="OIT-btn" onclick="OITbutton()">View</button>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        <tbody>


                <!-- .....other table bodies excluded for clarity -->


                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

The relevant css:

```
#tablediv{
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#tr-test{
background-color: #2C3446;
max-width: 100%

}

#table1-heading{
text-align: center;
}

#OIT-btn, #elec-btn, #maint-btn{
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `meta` with `viewport` in `head`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I notice if I don't specify the position of the elements they automatically go to the center. But if I want it right or left aligned (I don't) it will apply those changes."?

Comment: Yes, I have `meta` with `viewport` in `head`.

Comment: and @divy3993 I mean, so any kind of alignment I make is being applied, but it doesn't remain in that position as the table shrinks. I want it to be center aligned, as the table moves, but applying that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Okay, So if I am getting you correctly, you are talking about `table` header which has `OIT Work Order Maintenance Costs` *text* and a `view` *button*, to be always centered regardless of table scrolls or not on shrinking your devices' screen width. Am I correct?

Comment: @divy3993 yes, that is correct!

Comment: @MelodyAnoni, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I would like to suggest, to solve your issue.

**The Issue:**

Currently your **Table Header** is exceeding in `width` than the available horizontal space with its parent `container`, instead of shrinking on reducing/resizing of screen width.

**1. Keeping your HTML structure as it is.**

- Make the header tables' `max-width` to `100%`, in a way that it must not go beyond available space horizontally in any case.
- The real reason is `overflow-x:auto;` Remove it from `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">` which wraps your header table.

This must solve your issue.

**2. Updating your HTML markup.**

You may take two separate containers holding two different tables, i.e. for the header(containing `OIT Work Order Maintenance Costs` & a button) and content.

The reason you can do it without any issue is your both header and the content table does not relatively have the same numbers of columns or relate in design.

I hope this helps you. Also if you want an example to understand, would request you to post whatever you have in your HTML & CSS relating to your issue.

## Update

I would suggest to separate your HTML markup for tables as below:

```css
#tablediv{
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#tr-test{
background-color: #2C3446;
max-width: 100%

}

#table1-heading{
text-align: center;
}

#OIT-btn, #elec-btn, #maint-btn{
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2 id="title" class="hidden" align="center">OIT Facilities Costs
       <p id="subtitle">by location<p>
    </h2>
</div>
<p>This application visualizes 3 kinds of data </p>
<br>
<div id="dashboard1-div" align="center">
    <div id="charts1-div">
        <div id="tablediv">
           <!-- Your header table --> 
            <table class="container">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="tr-test">
                        <td>
                            <p id="table1-heading" class="hidden">OIT Work Order Maintenance Costs</p>
                            <button id="OIT-btn" onclick="OITbutton()">View</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               <tbody>
            </table>
           <!-- Your body table  -->
            <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <table class="container">
                    <!-- .....other table bodies excluded for clarity -->
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Separated tables here on above example. As the real issue here is because of your content table requires more horizontal space(width) than available which brings the scrolls and your header table also takes the same space and centers everything according to that space.

For more created here an example for same:  [Link](https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/wReEvp)

## Update 2

```css
#tablediv{
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#tr-test{
background-color: #2C3446;
max-width: 100%

}

#table1-heading{
text-align: center;
}

#OIT-btn, #elec-btn, #maint-btn{
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

table { border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }

td, th {
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <h2 id="title" class="hidden" align="center">OIT Facilities Costs
           <p id="subtitle">by location<p>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <p>This application visualizes 3 kinds of data </p>
    <br>
    <div id="dashboard1-div" align="center">
        <div id="charts1-div">
            <div id="tablediv">
               <!-- Your header table --> 
                <table class="container">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="tr-test">
                            <td>
                                <p id="table1-heading" class="hidden">OIT Work Order Maintenance Costs</p>
                                <button id="OIT-btn" onclick="OITbutton()">View</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                   <tbody>
                </table>
               <!-- Your body table  -->
                <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                    <table class="container">
                        <!-- .....other table bodies excluded for clarity -->
                        
                        <tbody>
                            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                <th class="sorting_1">Airi</th>
                                <th>Satou</th>
                                <th>Accountant</th>
                                <th>Tokyo</th>
                                <th>33</th>
                                <th>2008/11/28</th>
                                <th>$162,700</th>
                                <th>5407</th>
                                <th>a.satou@datatables.net</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1">Airi</td>
                                <td>Satou</td>
                                <td>Accountant</td>
                                <td>Tokyo</td>
                                <td>33</td>
                                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                                <td>$162,700</td>
                                <td>5407</td>
                                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="even">
                                <td class="sorting_1">Angelica</td>
                                <td>Ramos</td>
                                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                                <td>London</td>
                                <td>47</td>
                                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                                <td>$1,200,000</td>
                                <td>5797</td>
                                <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>                   
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have discovered that meta with viewport it's essentially doing nothing for me, and I need `overflow-x:auto` to make the table responsive. Could it be possible that I'm working with html4 since `meta` with `viewport` only applies to html5? I've checked ways to know, but the way the html is structured doesn't clearly tell me which version I'm using. I've updated the code, did I apply the `max-width` the way you intended?  Also, in your second strategy, what properties would be applied to the two containers?

Comment: @MelodyAnoni, updated my answer, actually it has nothing to do with meta viewport in this case.

Comment: @MelodyAnoni, let me know if you still find it hard to solve the issue.

Comment: thanks so much for your awesome help. I've applied the changes and it works, problem is that I need the heading to be connected to the overall table. I'm currently working on an update.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: I made an update below my post. I needed to clarify that I need the header to always stay the same width as the table, so I don't think I can accomplish this by separating the header and the body into their own containers. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: I got it, but I am still confused with your HTML update you made in post above. Could you look into link [here](https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/wReEvp) once more if that's not a problem. Look closely how separated both table are and still wrapping both tables inside `<div id="tablediv">`.

Comment: Also better if you can share some live link of your website/web-page if you can. With same look and feel, would be better to explain it better.

Comment: Oh, yes, I made the updates from your link to my code to get the third image in the post, but didn't change the html for the post since it didn't solve the width issue. I can update the html to be what you suggested.  I'll get back to you soon with an update. Thanks so much. I will have to send you a cookie after all this.

Comment: Oh okay no worries, welcome! I have updated answer I want you to check once.

Comment: Ahh thank you. Now I have some other formatting things to work through but that at least solved that problem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Happy to help.